# Does app rollout percentage in play store applies to new installs

Tags: android, rollout

I mean to say if I rollout to 20% users, does that mean only 20% of the first time installers will see the new version and 80% of first time installers will see the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does that mean only 20% of the first time installers will see the new
>   version nd 80% of first time i stallers will see the old one?

That 20% includes the first time (new) and also the existing users. There is no differentiation between the new users and the existing users.

From the [doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en):

> New and existing users are eligible to receive updates from staged
>   rollouts and are chosen at random for each new release rollout.